# Valid method to load product object

Tags: magento2

You have created a module controller that responds to the following URL: `/mycompany/product/load/id/123`.
Which two methods will load the product model by ID as specified in the URL? (Choose two.)

> A. `\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product::load($productModel,
>   $id)`
>
> B.
>   `\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection::load()->fetchById($id)`
>
> C.
>   `\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection::fetchItemById($id)`
>
> D. `\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface::getById($id)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use option B as well as option D, but i suggest use Api option (D), it is best while retrieve product information in magento.

Comment: Option B?
fetchById does Magento having this method?

Answer (score 0):

You should always use repositories. So use D

Repositories are part of the Service Contracts (they are implementations of interfaces in Api), this means they are meant as a public interface to other modules. You can find more information about this here: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/service-contracts/service-contracts.html

Also, you shoud always implement the API INTERFACE in your constructor instead of it's impementation.

If you need more information on how retrieve data and search with repositories you can find some examples in magento devdocs: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/searching-with-repositories.html